# Is there a zero [ 0 ] constant somewhere in any Microsoft .NET class?

Tags: c#, math, constants, zero, .net

I'm just curious and I know it's not of much value, but here it goes...

I think that I have seen something like that somewhere but I'm not sure.

I mean something like this:

```
var zero = Class.Zero;
```

I tried looking at the `Math` class but it's not there.

I also know that I can use an unsigned value type like `ushort.Min` to get a Zero ( 0 ) value; it's not what I'm asking here... :D

Comment: it is called 0  .....

Comment: Are you afraid that the value of 0 will change?

Comment: I'm genuinely curious as to why you need such a constant? Is there a specific reason you need `Decimal.Zero` instead of just... `0`?

Comment: @Karl: as I said it's not of much value. I prefer to use what already exists (constants) in the framework instead of typing that myself. Right now I'm working with a View (ASP.NET MVC) and I wanted to show the value $ 0.00 to the user. It happens that I was working with a `decimal` value type and just forgot to look at the Decimal class. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's one for [`Decimal.Zero`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.zero.aspx) and a few other more complex types like [`TimeSpan.Zero`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.zero.aspx), [`IntPtr.Zero`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.zero.aspx) and [`BigInteger.Zero`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.zero.aspx). But for regular numeric types, just use `0`.

Comment: Oh... `Decimal.Zero` is the one I mentioned in my question. I just couldn't remember where it was. :)

Answer (score 14):

Do you mean `default(T`)?

```
int zero = default(int);
```

This represents the *default value* for a given type, for `int` this is 0. You should not use this if you *know already* you need zero though, only in the case that you have a type at run time for which you need the default value.

Answer (score 5):

The .Net Framework doesn't define constants for values like `0`.  If you want to use `0` just use `0`

Defined numeric constants in the .Net Framework typically revolve around the limits of a given numeric type, values which hold special relevance or cases where the zero value requires special / complex initialization.  For example

- Int32.Max
- Int32.Min
- Double.NaN

The literal `0` doesn't fit these categories for most numeric types (`Decimal` being one exception)

Answer (score 3):

Some immutable reference types have pre-defined instances for "empty" values.  String, for example, defines String.Empty.  This is done because a valid String--even one with no characters--must reference a valid heap object, but if there are a thousand empty String variables they may all refer to the same heap object.  Unless an application doesn't happen to use any empty strings at all, creating one empty-string instance at application startup and allowing it to be shared among everyone who needs an empty string will be more efficient than creating a new empty string object every time one is needed.

No such benefit would exist with value types.  Although there are some value-type constants declared (e.g. Math.Pi), their declaration is for convenience, not efficiency.  Saying "myDouble = Math.Pi" is no more efficient than "MyDouble = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510#"--it's just easier to read and validate (would anyone looking at the above code notice if the first "328" were mistyped as "238")?  If one wants a floating-point constant zero, the most natural and easiest-to-read notation would simply be 0#.

Comment: Your point is well taken, but I note that different versions of the framework differ as to whether the empty string is inlined across assemblies or not. Some of them do, some of them do not. I'm not sure what motivated the change. And also, doubles are only accurate to ~15 decimal places so whether the first 328 was mistyped as 238 is irrelevant; the compiler will be discarding those digits anyway.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: My main point was that value-type constants are different from reference-type "constant instances".  I didn't remember exactly how far double-precision values go out, and just grabbed a convenient reference value of pi.  The value of math.pi is displayed in vs as "3.1415926535897931" but the next larger floating-point number is "3.1415926535897936", so I just happened to select a group of digits just past the point of significance.  Oh well.